# Can you simply mount a new OS image from within an existing operating system to install it?

Tags: linux, windows-10, ubuntu, mount, operating-systems

[image]I am currently using Windows 10 and wanted to **install** Ubuntu 20.04 on it (**dual boot**).

I know that the standard way is to use a USB Flash drive or some other external source to install a new operating system.

But is it possible that I simply ***mount* the downloaded Ubuntu 20.04 .iso image file** from my current OS (Windows 10) just like I can with some other applications?

What all should I know about it? Currently, I don't find much related to my question on the internet (maybe it's really stupid XD ).

Comment: You cannot install ubuntu from within Windows, mounting the image just allows you to browse it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But is it possible that I simply mount the downloaded Ubuntu 20.04 .iso image file from my current OS (Windows 10) just like I can with some other applications?

**It is not currently possible to install Ubuntu from within Windows.**  While it is possible to mount the ISO, and view the contents of the image, you will be unable start the installation process from within Windows.

It used to be possible to install Ubuntu from within Windows, this was called Windows-based Ubuntu Installer ([WUBI](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Wubi)), that effort has been abandoned and is not supported by any version of Windows.  You might look into running a Windows Subsystem for Linux, specifically, `Windows Subsystem on Linux 2` (WSL 2) while running `Windows 10 version 2004`.

**Canonical has made it clear, that there suggested method to this problem, is to use [Ubuntu for Windows 10](http://%20[Install%20Ubuntu%20for%20Windows%2010][1]).**

> What all should I know about it?

There isn't anything to know about it.  **If using WSL 2 isn't an option, then your only recourse, is to install Linux normally.**

Background:

- [Announcing WSL 2](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/announcing-wsl-2/)
- [WSL2 will be generally available in Windows 10, version 2004](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/wsl2-will-be-generally-available-in-windows-10-version-2004/)
- [What’s new in the Windows 10 May 2020 Update](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2020/05/27/whats-new-in-the-windows-10-may-2020-update/)
- [Install Ubuntu for Windows 10](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-ubuntu-on-windows#3-install-ubuntu-for-windows-10)